# React-navigation from Android fragment to Android activity

Tags: android, react-native, android-fragments, react-navigation, brownfield

I have a brownfield react-native application. On one of my native Activities, I have reactRootView rendered inside an Android Fragment.  Inside this fragment, I load a react-navigation stack.

When a user clicks a button to navigate to a route, instead of navigating inside the fragment, I want the route to load on a new Activity. Is this possible? I thought if I used the native stack and react-native-screens there could be a feature that would let me do this, but I couldnt find such thing:

[image]

Thanks for any help